# Typedef with or without typename on structs and enum, what are pro/cons for each and what is best practice?

Tags: c, struct, enums, typedef, c99

Edit: Regarding closing the question for being opinion based.
I am specifically fishing for anything that is strictly objective and not subjectivity. If there is no objective difference then the answer that states so gets the checkmark. There seems to be definitive objective differences though.

---

Regarding the how and why to use typedef in C is contained in numerous questions here on SO, but none seem to describe which usecase should be used, or the pro/cons for each.

Most questions regarding the subject revolves around this

```c
struct Bar {
    int value;
};

struct Foo {
    int value;
};
typedef struct Foo Foo;

struct Bar mybar; // Have to add keyword struct for it to work
Foo myfoo;        // Works without struct keyword
```

My question is more what is the best practice or what should one avoid for which reasons? Could there be issues with using any of the examples below? Or in case of different answers due to context, what are the pro/cons of the given examples

```c
// 1
typedef struct {
    int value;
} Foo;
```

```c
// 2
typedef struct Foo {
    int value;
} Foo;
```

```c
// 3
typedef struct Foo_s {
    int value;
} Foo_t;
```

```c
// 4
typedef struct Foo {
    int value;
} Foo_t;
```

Should any of these be avoided, and why? If any of these is not as good, are the same exact points valid for enums? I feel that the whole subject is a bit vague and I havent atleast found anything clear on the issue, so I'm just double checking so that nothing comes back to bite me later.

If there are other variations I can add them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a typedef declaration similar to this

```
// 1
typedef struct {
    int value;
} Foo;
```

you can not refer to the structure within the structure definition. So for example you can not declare a structure that denotes a node of a linked list because within the structure you need to refer to a pointer to the structure type that points to the next node.

In this typedef definition

```
// 3
typedef struct Foo_s {
    int value;
} Foo_t;
```

two different names `Foo_s` and `Foo_t` only confuse readers of code. For example it can be written like

```
struct Foo_s f = malloc( sizeof( Foo_t ) );
```

or

```
Foo_t f = malloc( sizeof( struct Foo_s ) );
```

This typedef definition

```
// 4
typedef struct Foo {
    int value;
} Foo_t;
```

has the same problem. For example if you will encounter two declarations like this

```
struct Foo f1;
```

and

```
Foo_t f2;
```

it is difficult to say whether the both types are the same.

So I prefer the following typedef definition

```
// 2
typedef struct Foo {
    int value;
} Foo;
```

Now you know that the identifier `Foo` is reserved for the structure.

Answer (score 2):

For fast reading and misuse confusion of different names, I'd like to recommend this form:

```
typedef struct Foo {
    int value;
} Foo;
```

There's nothing right or wrong, but it's all about personal preferences and practices.

Comment: Your reply would then mean there is none program-technical pro/cons to either of these, only subjective differences. Is this correct?

Comment: @trondhe Sure. However, you can relate to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/612328/difference-between-struct-and-typedef-struct-in-c) for more info.

Comment: It states the difference that is has to be defined in the tag namespace (in c++) to be forward declared. Is this valid for c as well?

Comment: Also another comment: It just came to mind, does this affect compiler errors or the debugging experience at all? Which relates back to pro/cons.

Comment: @trondhe Don't worry about that, as I studied this case while studying programming in C.

Have a good day :)

Comment: Im pedantic by nature. Ill hold you to it if I ever get any <anonymous struct> error which the compiler tells me nothing about! Thanks for the reply! :)

Answer (score 1):

Most of these cases have their weighting based on factors like code-readability/convenience/preference and limitations

```
typedef struct {
    int value;
} Foo;
```

Example 1: One is correct and if you're looking convenience and much shorter code/code lines for some reason but it's limitations like you can only use it like `Foo a;` and not `struct Foo a;`

```
typedef struct Foo {
    int value;
} Foo;
```

Example 2. Like Example 1 except for the declaration limitation where in Example 2 you can declare like `Foo a;` and `struct Foo a;`

```
typedef struct Foo_s {
    int value;
} Foo_t;
```

Example 3: This example has the readability/maintainability factor that 1 & 2 don't have. Like if other people, or even yourself way in the future, are going to be looking at the code, 3 would definitely be better to read and understand without any confusion between type names. This is why it is a standard in many places to name stuff like typedefs/enums/structs like that.

```
typedef struct Foo {
    int value;
} Foo_t;
```

Example 4: same goes for 4 as 3

Comment: Now there is competition. You perfer example 4 it seems, but the other two perfers example 2. Interesting. Is there any benefit to be able to differentiate between `Foo` and `Foo_t` in usage of it? Does it really help? If both are defined as `typedef struct Foo Foo;` and knowing the difference has no real use-cases, it would seem that would be preferable?

Comment: @trondhe there's no competition I just prefer 3 because the environment I work in, a lot of people write code that a lot of other people have to review and code readability is important when working in teams. No there isn't really any technical benefit. If you're working on solo projects and you don't like long lines of code then any between 1 & 2 will be fine (I do that a lot of times on solo projects too)

Comment: Yeah I'm just really trying to fish for anything that could possibly be objective pro/cons and not just subjective style. I like being pedantically sure :) I am also in an environment which I am changing a public (in house) API, so im just taking extra precaution of doing this as good as possible when im first making changes.